# Height not real 100% when vertical scollbar is present

Tags: html, css

I have a problem.

I have made a basic layout, the problem is that the height:100% of sidebar and wrapper don't adapt themselves to real height.

Basically this is the layout

```
<div class="sidebar collapse">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <div class="user"></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <h5>Men&ugrave;</h5>
    <a href="#" class="icon-conten">Contenuti</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <a href="#">Men&ugrave;</a>
      <a href="#">Barra laterale</a>
      <a href="#">Footer</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="icon-config">Configurazione</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="box page-toggle"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
    <div class="page-title box">
      Title
    </div>
  <div class="page-content box">
      Content
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is part of the css

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
.sidebar {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .sidebar {
      left: 0 !important; } }

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .collapse {
    left: -250px; } }

.wrapper {
  background: #EEE;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px; }
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%; } }
  .wrapper .box {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
```

I made this pen hoping to explain better the problem.... :)

https://codepen.io/globdug/pen/errbMY

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use flex for your design instead of absolutely positioning your divs.
See my version on codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GddzNw

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar collapse">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="...">
    <div class="user">User</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <h5>Men&ugrave;</h5>
    <a href="#" class="icon-conten">Contenuti</a>
    <div class="submenu">

      <a href="#">Men&ugrave;</a>
      <a href="#">Barra laterale</a>
      <a href="#">Footer</a>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="icon-config">Configurazione</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="box page-toggle"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
    <div class="page-title box">
      Title
    </div>
  <div class="page-content box">

    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1><br /><br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <em>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</em> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br /><br />
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2><br /><br />
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</strong> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li><li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li></ul><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3><ol><li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li><li>Ut enim ad minim veniam</li></ol><h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4><br /><br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br />


  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
$sidebar-width: 250px;
$padding: 20px;

// colori
$primary: #ff9800;
$primary-l1: #ffad33;
$primary-l2: #ffc266;
$primary-l3: #ffd699;
$primary-l4: #ffebcc;
$primary-l5: #fff9f0;
$primary-d1: #e68a00;
$primary-d2: #cc7a00;
$primary-d3: #b36b00;
$primary-d4: #995c00;
$primary-d5: #804d00;

// sfondi
$bg-dark: #333;
$bg-light: #FFF;
$bg-wrapper: #EEE;

// colori testi
$text-on-dark: $primary-l5;
$text-on-light: $primary-d5;

// breakpoints
$breakpoint: 800px;

@mixin box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*{
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

html,body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    font-family: "Ubuntu", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom: $padding;
    padding:0px;
}
h1{ font-size: 30px }
h2{ font-size: 26px }
h3{ font-size: 24px }
h4{ font-size: 22px }
h5{ font-size: 20px }
h6{ font-size: 18px }

hr{
    padding:0px;
    margin:$padding 0px;
    border:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.sidebar{
    width:$sidebar-width;
    height:100%;
    background: $bg-light;
    @include box-shadow;
}
.collapse{
    @media (max-width:$breakpoint){
        left:- $sidebar-width;
    }

}
.wrapper{
    background:$bg-wrapper;
    width: calc(100% - #{$sidebar-width});
    height: 100%;
    padding:$padding;
    @media (max-width:$breakpoint){
        width:100%;
    }
    .box{
        background:#fff;
        padding:$padding;
        margin-bottom:$padding;
        @include box-shadow;
    }
}
.page-title{
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:500;
    &:first-letter{
        color:$primary;
    }
}

.page-toggle{
    display:none;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:$primary;
    &:hover{
        color:#000;
        background:$primary;
    }
}

@media (max-width:$breakpoint){
    .page-title{
        display:block;
        margin-left:50px + $padding;
    }
    .page-toggle{
        width:50px;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        display:inline-block;
    }
}

.sidebar-header{
    padding:$padding 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    img{
        margin:0px auto 5px;
        width:50px;
        height:auto;
        border:0px;
        border-radius:50%;
        display:block;
    }
    .user{
        letter-spacing:2px;
        font-variant:small-caps;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        font-size:1.2em;
        font-weight:700;
        &::first-letter{
            color:$primary;
        }
    }
}
.sidebar-menu{
    h5{
        padding:0px $padding;
    }
    a{
        padding:10px $padding;
        display:block;
        color:#000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        &:hover{
            background:$primary;
            &::before{
                color:#000;
            }
        }
        &::before{
            font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight:900;
            padding-right:10px;
            color:$primary;

        }
    }
    >.link-active{
        background: $primary;
        font-size:1.1em;
        &::before{
            color:#000 !important;
        }
    }
}
.submenu{
    display:none;
    font-size:0.9em;
    background:$primary-l4;
    a{
        padding:3px $padding;
        &:hover{
            background:$primary-l1;
        }
        &::before{
            content:"\f105";
            margin-left:3px;
            padding-right:13px;
        }
    }
}

.icon-conten::before{   content:"\f15c"; }
.icon-config::before{   content:"\f013"; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this way the problem still persist...
At the end I have used position:fixed and not absolute to make it work .